# Не работает код?

Tags: html, jquery, touch-event

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CC</title>
    <style>
        .block1 {
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  cursor: grab;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="block1" id="circle">
     </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById('circle');
      var listener = function(e) {
      div.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
      }
      $('#circle').on('touchstart', function(){
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', listener);
      })
      $('*').on('touchend', function(){
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', listener);
      });

  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Опишите, что Ваш код должен делать, пожалуйста

Comment: Не работает код?

Comment: Автор написал код и решил спросить тут работает он или нет? В чем вопрос?